# How does the class concept and syntax, especially for encapsulation and member access, of Java compare to the one of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, class, encapsulation

I know a lot about Java, but I´m absolutley new to Javascript. I know some background information about the language itself, but thats it. Now im using a certain API and therefor I need Js. So i downloaded Node.js and started to write some code. I´ve realized that there many diffrences to Java and I didnt find any good solutions. Here is an example:

```
public class Client {

private String username;
private String password;
private String host;
private final int port = 25565;

public Client(String username, String password, String host) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.host = host;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public int getPort() {
    return port;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public String getHost() {
    return host;
}
}
```

This is a normal Java class for oop. Could somebody give me an example, how to make something like this in Js and how to access such an class / file (in js) ?

Comment: [Classes - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: If you are coming from Java, take a look at TypeScript

Comment: JavaScript is not Java. Everything in JS is an object, also classes are objects. Don't even try to use JavaScript like if it is Java, it's a brand new world. If you're confused i advise you the free book "you don't know JS" of Simpson

Answer (score 1):

I won't give the same answer as sami, but there is another way to create classes in JS that does allow for variables only accessible to the parent:

```js
function Client(username, passwd, host) {
    const port = 25565; //this is private

    this.getUsername = () => username;  //this is public
    this.getPort = () => port;
    this.getPassword = () => passwd;
    this.getHost = () => host;
}

var client = new Client("john doe", "pass", "www.example.com");
client.getUsername();   //returns "john doe"
```

In JS, classes are nothing more than functions. Member functions of classes are closures. Also note, how concise the code is due to the arrow functions and how the parameters of the `Client` constructor function are accessible to the closures within this scope. You can also modify their values as if you declared them with `let` or `var` within this scope.

Comment: The first three let assignements are not necessary; the arguments `username`, `passwd` and `host` are already accessible within the scope of each closure that is going to be created with every `Client` instantiation call. And `let MyPort` might be changed to `const myPort`. Please consider changing the example code accordingly

Comment: I made your suggested changes, but also added clarification that the 3 parameters are mutable.

Answer (score -1):

In Nodejs you can create a class, inherits the same as JAVA. But nodejs don't have a variable type or public/private method. For convention add _ with variable name as to represent as a private variable.

To access a js file use `module.exports` with the class name.
Use `require` for accessing class in another js file.

If you have a setup of package.json with es6 babel. you can directly use `export default` in place of `module.exports`
and  `import` for accessing class in another js file. More details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

client.js

```
class Client {
   port = 25565;
   constructor(username, password, host) {
      this._username = username;
      this._password = password;
      this._host = host;
   }

   getUsername() {return this._username}

   getPort() {return this.port}

   getPassword() {return this._password}

   getHost() {return this._host}
}

module.exports = Client;
```

main.js

```
var Client = require('./client.js');

console.log(new Client('pr','password', '2020'))
```

**Run:** node main.js